# Asynchronously screenscraping pages and storing them with Active Record?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, concurrency, screen-scraping

I need to screenscrape a bunch of pages and store them in a database using ActiveRecord. I messed around using EventMachine and Typhoeus but I get flaky results, mostly mysteriously empty records getting saved.

What's the trick? I had the best results with scraping pages and writing them to disk, then inserting them into the DB, but I'd really like to do it in a single pass.

Is anybody doing this successfully?

Comment: The problem could occur in many different places. Without sample URLs and sample code we can't give you a very useful answer.

Comment: Have you got it to work?

Comment: Why would you blame the scraping tools for empty ActiveRecords? You either get blank pages, or you don't. Whether and how you store them is a separate problem.

Comment: I dunno, concurrency problems.  That's why I'm asking. Have you got it to work? What do you do?

Comment: You don't give us enough information to test it "working"... Have you tried adding log messages before and after the screen-scrape?  Possibly indicating (in the after-scrape log message) how long the page is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your threads are sharing an AR connection. This will cause problems, and anyway concurrency won't get records into your database any faster. I suggest you download concurrently and insert them in a single thread (like you've been doing.)